# Como ejecutar archivo python en vim

Tags: python, vim

Hola estoy aprendiendo a utilizar vim en linux(lubuntu), he descargado python.vim. Quiero ejecutar un archivo python,  he intantado utilizar

> :w !python

pero me sale:

> /bin/bash: python: orden no encontrada
>
> el intérprete de órdenes devolvió 127

¿Qué necesito algun script? o que me recomendais.

Comment: ¿Instalaste Python? ¿Lo puedes invocar desde la línea de comandos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que mí programa se llama `example.py` y que tengo instalado Python.

Podrías hacerlo dentro del intérprete de la forma en que lo tienes o de la siguiente forma:

```
:! python example.py
```

**O también**:

```
:! python %
```

Donde ya el porcentaje asume que es el propio fichero que deseas ejecutar.

**Por ejemplo**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hará **lo siguiente**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún así, ¿por qué no usas un IDE como Vscode? Y en caso de usar vim, ¿por qué mejor no tienes dos ventanas? Una donde veas el código y otra donde ejecutes el script llamando a la ruta de éste, **siguiendo el ejemplo anterior**:

```
python3 example.py
```

En caso de no tenerlo instalado, prueba a hacerlo:

-[Guía instalación Python](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-python-command-not-found/)

Al estar en Lubuntu puedes instalarlo con:

-**Python**:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

-**Python3**:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido muy útil.

Comment: Me alegro, para eso estamos. Saludos.